# How to write a Java class which interprets numeric user inputted data as Days of the week

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm new to Java and learning it. I've come across this question which I'm trying to understand.

How can I write a Java class that has 2 fields which hold the following info:

- RoomNumber (A String)
- MeetDays (A String)

The MeetDays considers Sunday to be day 1. A user should enter the day number for each day the class meets.

Example:
if classes are held Tues and Thurs, user will enter 35. If user enters an invalid number ranges such as '11' or '233' etc. An exception will be thrown.

I figure to do a switch statement here but I am just unsure how to proceed. I figure this might be an easy question for an experienced Java Developer. Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Edit:

```
public class SectionNumber {

    private String roomNumber;
    private String meetDays;

    public SectionNumber() {}

    public SectionNumber(String roomNumber, String meetDays) {
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.meetDays = meetDays;
    }

    public String getRoomNumber() {
        return roomNumber;
    }

    public void setRoomNumber(String roomNumber) {
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    }

    public String getMeetDays() {
        return meetDays;
    }

    public void setMeetDays(String meetDays) {
        this.meetDays = meetDays;
    }


    // not sure how to proceed here
    public void classMeetDays(String userInput) {

        switch (meetDays) {
        case userInput:

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to write any code to create this class? Have you looked at your textbook and/or tutorial to determine the structure of what such a class would look like? For the sake of your learning, you doing it would be far more beneficial than us providing code to you.

Comment: There are 7 days in a week (I hope you know that), and first day is Sunday, numbered 1, so all weekdays are 1-7. A string representing weekdays, e.g. `35` is 3=Tuesday, 5 = Thursday, means that digits must all be 1-7, and increasing, e.g. `53` and `38` would both be wrong.

Comment: What is the format of the meetDays String?

Comment: I will post my code shortly

Comment: @SantiagoBenoit yes that is correct

Comment: I was thinking to make meetDays a String[] (array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> dayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        int userInputNumber = 1234567;

        String userInputAsString = String.valueOf(userInputNumber);


        for (int i = 0; i < userInputAsString.length(); i++) {
            char dayAsNumericChar = userInputAsString.charAt(i);

            String day;
            switch (dayAsNumericChar) {
            case '1':
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case '2':
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case '3':
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case '4':
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case '5':
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case '6':
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            case '7':
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalide number: " + dayAsNumericChar);
            }
            if (dayList.contains(day)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Day: " + day + " is picked twice");
            }
            dayList.add(day);


        }
        System.out.println(userInputAsString);
        for (String s : dayList) {
            System.out.println(" -> " + s);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahh I see exactly what you did here, cleaver...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to declare `meetDays` as an instance variable in your class. This class should also contain a method that iterates over the days inputted and adds them to `meetDays`. For instance:

```
private void setDays(String input) {
    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        switch (input.charAt(i)) {
            case '1':
                meetDays += "Sunday ";
                break;
            case '2':
                meetDays += "Monday ";
                break;
            // and so on for the remaining days
            default:
                //throw the exception here
        }
    }
    meetDays = meetDays.trim();
}
```

Comment: For some reason I can't +1 your post...maybe bc I'm a noob

Comment: It seems here I would have to account for every combination of days i.e. 23456, 24,35,246 etc..

Comment: The code I posted wouldn't account for commas and would simply throw an exception when it encountered one. You could add something in to handle that if you wish. Besides that, it will be able to account for any combination of days, since it would iterate over the input and add a day to `meetDays` for every digit in the input.